# how to join multiple rigged mesh and bones

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I rigged and weight painted a finger mesh, and now i need to connect the bones and the mesh to make the hand while maintaining the bone weights so i dont need to redo the weight paint for every finger, how do i go about doing this?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that you need to connect the bones and the mesh? do your bones and finger meshes already exist? or are they apart? it's not clear... anyway I'm afraid you'll have to redo the same job for every finger, unless someone knows a better way to do it?

Comment: i mean jointing multiple rigs, so jointing the bones, and jointing the already weight painted meshs into a single mesh and bone rig

Comment: keep a copy of your work so you have a safe version somewhere, then try to join the different meshes and bones into one object and one armature, it should work, but make sure that each bone has a unique name, if it's not the case several parts of the mesh will have the same vertex group name and the bones will control parts you don't want them to... also I guess you could need to make additional weight paints at the joints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. select bone and mesh and duplicate them.
2. select individual bones of the duplicate and rename them so they have unique bone names from the original. Renaming the bones will automatically rename weight painted the vertex groups.
3. apply location rotation and scale to the bones in object mode, and make sure all armatures have the same origin
4. select the mesh and hit ctrl J
5. select bones in the same order as you selected the meshs and hit ctrl J